# Problem trying to start a runnable jar from a C++ application

Tags: c++, jar, exec, runnable, shellexecute

I need to develop a .exe file that will launch a runnable .jar file which is stored on a subfolder called `core`. I built the C++ .exe application with `sublime text` and `mingw` and it's working fine but there is a small problem that I need to solve. When you execute the .exe file, during a minimum portion of time you can see a black window on screen which is disappearing in some milliseconds and after it the Java .jar application opens. This only happens if I use this .exe. If I double click in the runnable jar the black window doesn't appear.

**How can I avoid that black window which dissapears in some milliseconds?**

This is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() 
{
    ShellExecute(0, "open", "core.jar", NULL, "core", SW_SHOW); 
    return 0;
}
```

I tried also with this code and same result:

```
ShellExecute(0, "open", "cmd.exe", "/C .\\core\\core.jar", 0, SW_HIDE);
```

I'm aware there are other similar questions but none of them works for this problem and none of them seems to be applicable to Sublime and gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Use CreateProcess() or ShellExecuteEx() which will return you handle to the created process, and with that handle you can kill the process.
Here is an example showing how this works including error handeling.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void DisplayError(LPCTSTR errorDesc, DWORD errorCode)
{
    TCHAR errorMessage[1024] = TEXT("");

    DWORD flags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_MAX_WIDTH_MASK;

    FormatMessage(flags,
        NULL,
        errorCode,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        errorMessage,
        sizeof(errorMessage) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        NULL);

    std::cerr << "Error : " << errorDesc << "\n";
    std::cerr << "Code    = " << errorCode << "\n";
    std::cerr << "Message = " << errorMessage << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
    info.cb = sizeof(info);
    ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));

    std::string path = "D:\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_26\\bin\\java.exe";
    std::string cmdArgs = "java.exe -jar D:\\temp\\sample.jar";

    // Start the child process.     
    if (CreateProcess(path.c_str(), const_cast<char *>(cmdArgs.c_str()), NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
    {
        // Wait until child process exits.
        WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
        // Close process and thread handles.
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
    }
    else
    {       
        DWORD errorCode = GetLastError();
        DisplayError(TEXT("Unable to execute."), errorCode);        
    }

    //system("pause");
}
```

Comment: std::string path = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe";

Comment: OK, I see you issue now. Let me test that use case and get back to you soo,

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your call to ShellExecute. Your code is for a console application. Console applications, as one might guess, run in a console (that black window; same as you'd get if you ran cmd.exe).

You can just replace `main` with `WinMain`, and simply call `ShellExecute` in there to launch the jar, and there should be no resulting console window (assuming the jar itself isn't creating one).

See [14 B](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/mingwfaq.html#compilingandbuilding) for how to make a 'windows' app with MingW.

Comment: in the link of the possible duplicate, they are using Visual Studio, I'm using sublime and gcc, please remove the duplicate request, and even if i achieve to launch it in a window, the window probably will be visible as the console, both are windows. If you think that I can apply that visual studio answer to my problem with sublime and gcc, please, can you share a small sample code?

Comment: Sorry, neglected to notice that slightly important difference :). Though, the idea holds; a "Windows" application doesn't necessarily have to have a window.

Comment: but the duplicate request is still present, can you delete it please?

Comment: ah, my bad. for some reason, i thought deleting the comment was enough. should be retracted now. has been a weird week, heh

Answer (score 0):

Finally I discovered that is enough with adding `-mwindows` to the gcc compile command:

```
gcc -o launcher launcher.cpp -mwindows
```